# What are the implicit indexes added by oracle

Tags: oracle

As per my knowledge, when a primary key is defined in a table an index is created for that column. So I don't have to create an index explicitly.

Are there any other way an implicit indexes added by oracle?

Comment: AFAIK this also applies to PK/UK constraints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only for primary key constraints and unique key constraints.

Note that this is an implementation detail only so that those constraints can be enforced efficiently.

Comment: Thanks. I found this contradicting. https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:36858373078604

Comment: Tom's answer is better than mine.

Comment: is there anything else that can be added to it? Else Is it ok if I delete the post because of low views?